# Lambda expressions in Kotlin

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

Consider the following Java class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public interface Something {
        void doSomething();
    }

    public void call(Something something) {}
}
```

In Kotlin, I can use a lambda expression as follows:

```
SomeClass().call { 
    // do something
}
```

But if I define the following method in Kotlin (using the same interface):

```
fun call(something: Something) {}
```

Then this call:

```
call {
    // do something
}
```

Would generate a type mismatch error. Why?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Kotlin only supports SAM conversions for Java methods, because Kotlin itself has function types. Normally, Kotlin functions should be taking `() -> Unit` rather than `Something`. If you really need it to take `Something`, you can use a SAM constructor:

```
call(Something { /* do something */ })
```

Any SAM type (Java interface with one abstract method) automatically gets such a constructor function that converts a lambda to its instance.

Comment: That decision looks weird for me. Consider `List<(T) -> Unit>` vs `List<OnChangeListener<T>>`. The second carries much more information. Fortunately there is a workaround: we can use java code freely in kotlin projects.

Comment: Named function types are a different story. And they will be supported in the next version of Kotlin

Comment: @Yaroslav huh, same problem, `List<(T) -> Unit>` looks awful

Comment: For better understanding  you can see here : https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/lambda-expressions-in-kotlin

Answer (score 10):

Kotlin requires that call takes something of interface `something`.

```
() -> Kotlin.Unit
```

Does not satisfy the type requirement.

You can do this

```
call (object : Something {
    override fun doSomething() {
        println("Passing an interface to call in kotlin!")
    }
})
```